# SQL select issue : get max value for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

I have a problem with my SQL select, I need to get the max value for the column (`currentcount`) per each day for the period between `DateDebut` and `DateFin`, but the returned result show me multiple values.

My SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @dateDebut DATE, 
        @dateFin DATE, 
        @SITA_METIER VARCHAR(20), 
        @DEFSITE VARCHAR(20);

SET @dateDebut = '01/01/2017';
SET @dateFin = '31/12/2018';


SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) AS Date, 
    MAX(currentcount) AS MAXUSERS
FROM
    logintracking 
WHERE
    attemptdate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @dateDebut) AND CONVERT(DATE, @dateFin)
    AND logintracking.clientaddr IN ('10.118.254.21', '10.118.254.156') 
GROUP BY
    attemptdate, currentcount
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLD0v.jpg)

Desired result: only the **max value** for the column (`currentcount`) for each day

PS: `attemptdate` type is `Timestamp`, that's why I need to cast it into a simple date.

I also tried to use 'having' function but still get multiple values

Comment: You typically GROUP  BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `group by CONVERT(Date,attemptdate)`

Comment: i have tried this and it still show me the same result

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: If you use jarlh's `GROUP BY` clause, you cannot get duplicate days. You probably still have `currentcount` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already use `GROUP BY` the `distinct` is no make sense, so the `distinct` can be removed.

then you just modify `CONVERT(Date,attemptdate)` instead of `attemptdate` in `Group by`, and only need to `group by CONVERT(Date,attemptdate)`

```
select CONVERT(Date,attemptdate) as Date, max(currentcount) as MAXUSERS
from logintracking 
where attemptdate between @dateDebut and @dateFin
  and logintracking.clientaddr in ('10.118.254.21', '10.118.254.156') 
group by CONVERT(Date,attemptdate)
```

**Note:**

Your `@dateDebut` and `@dateFin` already are `Date` type. No need to use `CONVERT` function.

Comment: @Anass Glad to help you can mark this answer if that help you :)

Comment: @Anass: And do you understand why? `GROUP BY xyz` means one result row per `xyz`. If you want one result row per day, you need something like `GROUP BY day` and not `GROUP BY day, something_else`.